# Storing the current date in a database

Tags: model-view-controller

I am trying to store the current date in a field called date created for a particular order. I have this property in the data class for the order table:

```
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

The code to populate this field is : `DateCreated = DateTime.Today.Date;`

The correct value is being stored in the database but when I try to display it
the output is :

> 0001/01/01 00:00:00

Why it might be doing this?

Comment: "Model–View–Controller (MVC) is an architectural pattern used in software engineering. For Microsoft ASP.NET MVC, please use [tag:asp.net-mvc] tag instead. For Spring MVC, please use [tag:spring-mvc] tag instead."

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert it after reading it, for example:

```
DateTime my_date = DateTime.Parse((reader["date_created"]).ToString());
```

where *reader* is used for reading data from database and *date_created* is name of column in database.